# What is the effect of packages installed by snap on memory usage?

Tags: snap, memory-usage

I never used snaps before.
When reading the vague descriptions I assume it's implemented in a way really similar to containers.

This makes me assume that programs in snaps all use their own libraries. But because 'regular' programs use the default libs from the system I assume multiple libs will be loaded which will cost a lot of memory...

Is this indeed the case ?

Related: Are there other disadvantages with running programs installed with snaps ?
*(Note that I mention "running" instead of installing)*

Comment: Snaps can share libraries with other snaps (I see 3 shared components installed on my system that has few shared snaps), they also may not be able to do this. There are many *confinement* models available to the developer, which change the security & sharing capacity of the snap; so it's not a one-size-fits-all.

Comment: So, you've read "vague descriptions" and assumed a bunch of things? Why would you do something like that? Why not read clear discriptions and learn things instead?

Comment: That's the problem with descriptions... It's hard to know which one are correct and which ones are from people that think they know how everything works. I usually try to mix descriptions up and filter everything out that sounds wrong. This often results in a reasonable, but vague, descripton

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Snaps are indeed sandboxed applications that run in a confined environment, and contain, to an extent, their own libraries. These libraries that come with the snap cannot be used by other snaps. Therefore, memory requirement of multiple apps will be higher than in a system where these libraries can be shared by different applications.

Still, also within snap, some sharing is implemented through first of all the core snap, but also through optional use of [extensions](https://snapcraft.io/docs/supported-extensions) that avoid that the developer each time has to implement integration with for example Gnome and GTK, or KDE in the snap, and leads to reuse of these components between different snaps.